# C++ function doesn't return expected ouput

Tags: c++, encryption

I tried making a C++ Caesar Encryption. When I'm trying to encrypt **"QRSTUVWXYZ"** with key 2 then it outputs **STUVWXYZABðo**. But it does work right when I'm only ecrypting **"XYZ"** with key 2, which results in **"ZAB"**. Why doesn't the first work?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

//Encrypts Message

std::string encrypt(std::string msg, int key)
{

    long msg_length = msg.length();
    //Creates array for message
    char msg_arr[msg_length]{0};

    //Converts message string into array
    for (int i = 0; i < msg_length; i++)
    {
        msg_arr[i] = msg[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < msg_length; i++)
    {
        int new_uni{};

        char ch{msg_arr[i]};
        int uni{int(ch)};
        if (std::isupper(ch))
        {
            //Calculates new Unicode number for uppercase
            new_uni = 65 + (((uni - 65) + key) % 26);
        }
        else
        {
            //Calculates new Unicode number for lowercase
            new_uni = 97 + (((uni - 97) + key) % 26);
        }
        //Converts Unicode number into character
        char new_char{char(new_uni)};
        //Replaces old character with encrypted character
        msg_arr[i] = new_char;
    }
    //Converts array into string
    std::string s(msg_arr);
    return (s);
}
int main()
{

    std::string msg {"XYZ"};
    int key {2};
    std::cout << encrypt(msg, key) << std::endl;

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::string s(msg_arr);
```

This is using a `std::string`'s constructor that takes a `const char *` parameter. This must be a C-style string ***that's terminated by a `'\0'`***.

The shown code fails to properly null-terminate the `char` array, resulting in undefined behavior.

The shown code also uses non-standard C++ variable length arrays. Additionally, there is no apparent reason to use the `msg_arr` in the first place. The string can simply be modified, in place, in the `msg`, and the modified `msg` gets returned from this function. This will reduce the amount of code by approximately a half, not to mention that this would neatly eliminate the original cause of this bug.

Answer (score 2):

The C-style string you are using to initialize string s is not terminated with a NULL character. Also, VLAs are not standard in C++.